# Print PDF file Silently

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

**What I Want** : A folder where every time thousands of PDF comes. I want to print that file using C#. 
 **What will be the best option for me**

1. Create a service
2. Create a windows application

I want that my service or windows application print the file silently means no popup to select the user to select the printer default it will print every page only once and I want to make this application, which will not be dependent on `AcroRd32.exe` because several users are not using Acrobat reader on their system.

I have already look these posts:

- [print pdf silently in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580908/print-pdf-silently-in-c-sharp),
- [Send multiple pdf files from one folder to printer. ASPOSE.PDF. C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550552/send-multiple-pdf-files-from-one-folder-to-printer-aspose-pdf-c-sharp)

How can I complete this?

Comment: How about these link: [Print in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27429435/1050927), and [Print PDF by GhostScript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2600189/1050927)